# Highcharts: long vertical label to span multiple lines

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to make the vertical labels in HighCharts to span multiple lines instead of taking up a lot of height. I have tried several different approaches, but none seems to work.

I have tried:

```
labels: {
    style: { width: '100px', height: '100px' }        
}
```

I have also tried by setting useHTML to true and then using the formatter to display the label as a div. Then I sat a fixed width and height, but event this didn't work.

Fiddle showing the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/4Q9xE/

Any help/tips will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but it will look bad. Use something like this:

```
labels: {
    rotation: -90,
    formatter: function () {
        return this.value.replace(/ /g, '<br />');
    }
},
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4Q9xE/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will keep this approach in mind as a backup solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for me `useHTML` + `width` works fine, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/4Q9xE/2/

```
            labels: {
                rotation: -90,
                useHTML: true,
                style: {
                    width: 100 // or '100px'
                }
            }
```

Note: It won't work for exported chart.

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks :)   btw. why won't this work for exported chart?

Comment: You are right, this is caused by [this bug](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3585). It partially works, but it's not the result I would expect: http://jsfiddle.net/4Q9xE/8/ (yes, now it's necessary to disable textOverflow and enable whiteSpace).

Comment: FYI, the latest updated fiddle is not showing the first bar anymore.